# sorting the output of dist()

Tags: r, sorting, distance

I have a matrix `m`

```
m <- matrix ( 
  c( 2, 1, 8, 5,
     7, 6, 3, 4,
     9, 3, 2, 8,
     1, 3, 7, 4),
  nrow  = 4,
  ncol  = 4,
  byrow = TRUE)

rownames(m) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Now, I'd like to order the rows of `m` based on their respective distance, so I use `dist()`

```
dist_m <- dist(m)
```

`dist_m` is, when printed

```
          A         B         C
B  8.717798
C  9.899495  5.477226
D  2.645751  7.810250 10.246951
```

Since I want it ordered, I try `sort(dist_m)` which prints

```
[1]  2.645751  5.477226  7.810250  8.717798  9.899495 10.246951
```

Which is almost what I want. But I'd be more happy if it also printed the names of the two rows of which a number is the distance, something like

```
 2.645751  A  D
 5.477226  B  C
 7.810250  B  D
 8.717798  A  B
 9.899495  A  C
10.246951  C  D
```

This is certainly possible, but I have no idea how I could achieve this.

Comment: You haven't  specified col/row names though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to convert the `dist` to `matrix`, replace the upper triangle values as 0, `melt`, `subset` the non-zero values, and then `order` based on the 'value' column.

```
m1 <- as.matrix(dist_m)
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- 0
library(reshape2)
m2 <- subset(melt(m1), value!=0)
m2[order(m2$value),3:1]
#         value Var2 Var1
#4   2.645751    A    D
#7   5.477226    B    C
#8   7.810250    B    D
#2   8.717798    A    B
#3   9.899495    A    C
#12 10.246951    C    D
```

Or a `base R` option suggested by @David Arenburg after getting the 'm1'

```
 m2 <- cbind(which(m1!=0, arr.ind=TRUE), value= m1[m1!=0])
 m2[order(m2[,'value']),]
```

Comment: With base R you could do something like that I guess `cbind(which(m1!= 0, arr.ind = TRUE), value = m1[m1 != 0])` (after the first two lines). Where did you get the col/row names from btw?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that.  It may need a slight modification to include the row/column names.  I convert `dimnames(m) <- rep(list(LETTERS[1:4]), 2)`

Comment: @ARobertson I don't know.  My code was based on the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

**If you do have distance values = 0 in your dist object**

I started using the solution posted by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) to sort the output of a dist object, but in my case, I do have distance values = 0. To avoid discarding these with the `subset` step, I first converted the upper triangle to NA, an then the diagonal to NA as well, using `diag` (actually obtained a symmetric matrix from another program). Finally, instead of `subset`, I used `melt`, `na.omit`, and `order`:

```
library(reshape2)

#create matrix
 m <- matrix ( 
 c( 2, 1, 8, 5,
    2, 1, 8, 5,
    9, 3, 2, 8,
    1, 3, 7, 4),
    nrow  = 4,
    ncol  = 4,
    byrow = TRUE)

rownames(m) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

# use dist
dist_m <- dist(m)
dist_m 

# A and B are identical
             A         B         C
B  0.000000                    
C  9.899495  9.899495          
D  2.645751  2.645751 10.246951

m1 <- as.matrix(dist_m)
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- NA
diag(m1) <- NA
m2 <- melt(m1)
na.omit(m2[order(m2$value),3:1])
```

As a result, the pairwise distance value between A and B is preserved:

```
       value Var2 Var1
2   0.000000    A    B
4   2.645751    A    D
8   2.645751    B    D
3   9.899495    A    C
7   9.899495    B    C
12 10.246951    C    D
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
dm <- as.matrix(dist_m)
df <- data.frame(data = c(dm),
                 column = c(col(dm)),
                 row = c(row(dm)))

# get only one triangle
df <- df[df$row > df$column, ]

# put in order
df[order(df$data), ]

# for letters, add this
df$row <- LETTERS[df$row]
df$column <- LETTERS[df$column]
```